# Java file transfer - Incomplete files

Tags: java, sockets, filestream, file-transfer

So I have been working with sockets a bit in the past few days, and tried to make a basic program to transfer files. The files do transfer, but they are incomplete. Like, when I try to send a 500kB file, the receiver only gets a 480kB one. I searched for quite a while but I just cant find the error. I found on some similar errors that the streams werent closed, but mine is, and it still doesnt send properly.

Sender:

```
//Main
//...
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
//...

public void sendFile(File file)
{
    try {           
        buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        DataInputStream filestream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        filestream.readFully(buffer);

        DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        send("FILE_"+file.length()+"_\t"+file.getName());

        outStream.write(buffer);
        outStream.flush();

        filestream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

public void send(String data) {
    out.println(data);
}
```

Receiver:

```
DataInputStream inStream = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());

File file = new File("temp"+"\\"+expectedFile);
file.createNewFile();

BufferedOutputStream fileOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, false));

buffer = new byte[1024];

while (size > 0 && (receivedBytes = inStream.read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1)     
{     
    fileOut.write(buffer, 0, receivedBytes);
    fileOut.flush();     
    size -= receivedBytes;     
}  

fileOut.close();
```

Thanks for any kind of help :)

Comment: can you check number of bytes send(from client) and received(by server). are they equal ?

Comment: Total received Bytes: 22158                                           Sent Bytes: 30350

Comment: @Ashish So it's exactly 8kB, and it is the same amount of bytes missing no matter what total file size.

Comment: How do you calculate the value of size in the 2nd code block?

Comment: your code seems bit incomplete. Its good if you can provide some more information. thanks.

Comment: It's sent with the file name in the "send("FILE_"+buffer.length+"_\t"+file.getName());" instruction.

Comment: Did you verify that size actually contains the correct file size? in addition what does the send() method do?

Comment: send just does out.println(str), out being the socket OutputStream.

Comment: Do you know if the missing bytes are from the start/end of the file? can you post the code which reads the file name and size?

Comment: The missing 8kB are always at the start of the file.

Comment: @drorb else if (fromServer.startsWith("FILE_"))
       {
        expectedFile = fromServer.substring(fromServer.indexOf("_\t")+2);
        size = Long.parseLong(fromServer.substring(fromServer.indexOf('_')+1, fromServer.indexOf("_\t")));
        
       }

Comment: and how do you read the content of fromServer? why not just posting the entire code instead of revealing it piece by piece

Comment: `File.createNewFile()` is redundant here.

Comment: Because the whole code is a lot more than that and I was sure that the error was somewhere in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You drop the first read of data on the floor in this line:

```
int receivedBytes = inStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
```

Not really sure what that line of code is for (old debugging?).  You basically just need to remove it.

UPDATE:

You seem to indicate that you are sending additional metadata at the beginning of the stream.  My guess is that you are using some sort of BufferedInputStream/Reader when reading the initial metadata, and that is swallowing part of the subsequent file data.

You can somewhat solve this problem by wrapping the DataInputStream around the BufferedInputStream you are using to read the metadata.  You have to be careful, however, that whatever you are using to read the metadata doesn't read more data than it should.  It's actually trickier to do this than you might think.  You might want to look at using the DataInput/Output streams exclusively (use writeUTF/readUTF to handle the file name and writeLong/readLong to handle the file size).

Comment: Tried that and it is still incomplete, and when I send very small files they arent received at all. Thanks though.

Comment: Edited the code a bit and now, no matter how big the file being sent is, there is always 8KB missing in the beginning, the rest is sent completely.

Comment: @user3375858 - updated my answer.  just guesses, since you are missing some key code.

Comment: Works now! Just changed the readers and writers to DataInput- and OutputStreams and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

receiving end in general should look something like this...

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();
socket is = socket.getInputStream();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("fileName");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

int count;
while ((count = is.read(bytes)) > 0) {
        bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
    }
```